# Custom inputView for UITextField , how do I direct input back to the text field?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, first-responder, inputview

I have set a custom `inputView` to my `UITextField`. I need a way to display the data selected in my custom `inputView` in the `UITextfield`. I would like to achieve this the same way the system keyboard does it.

Does anyone know how this is done? How does the system keyboard get a reference to the `UITextfield` that is the first responder?

Comment: please be more precise, what do you mean by "direct input back to the textfield"? You want to focus the UITextField?

Comment: Sorry, i thought i was more precise in my explanation. What i mean is, i set the inputView property on a UITextField to my custom input view. So when the user pushes a button on my custom inputView, how do i get a reference to the UITextfield that is the current first responder so i can change the text property of that UITextfield to reflect the user's input?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> How does the system keyboard get a reference to the UITextfield that is the first responder?

It just asks the system for the first responder; unfortunately, that's a private UIKit method (or was, last I checked). You can find the first responder by recursing through the view hierarchy and asking each view, but that's pretty clumsy.

Instead, you can add a link to the text field on the input view (I'm assuming your input view is a custom UIView subclass):

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) UITextField* target;
```

Then use the UITextField delegate methods in your view controller to see when the text field is being focused:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField
{
    if ( [textField.inputView isKindOfClass:[MyInputView class]] )
        ((MyInputView*)textField.inputView).target = textField;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField*)textField
{
    if ( [textField.inputView isKindOfClass:[MyInputView class]] )
        ((MyInputView*)textField.inputView).target = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

When sending input from your custom input view back to the textfield, note that you can (should) use the `UIKeyInput` protocol methods that `UITextField` conforms to. Namely:

```
- (void)deleteBackward;
- (void)insertText:(NSString *)text;
```