# How do I connect custom keyboard to text field?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

I created a custom keyboard using buttons, but now I'm stuck with buttons that don't do anything.

How will I connect them to a text field?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be aware of the [inputView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html) property of the `UITextField`/`UITextView` classes. Basically you can have a custom view (your keyboard for example) and swap it with the default keyboard.

You can get some inspiration from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6T8N2yQC1ww) that shows how to create a custom keyboard - and how to connect it to your `textfield`/`textview`.

You can also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096979/custom-inputview-for-uitextfield-how-do-i-direct-input-back-to-the-text-field) for another way to connect your keyboard to a textfield/textview.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle buttons touchUpInside Action like this to insert text in uitextfield

```
@IBAction func btnQuestionAction(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    self.textDocumentProxy.insertText("?")

}
```

And to delete character using custom keyboard, You can use this:

```
@IBAction func btnBackspaceAction(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    self.textDocumentProxy.deleteBackward()
}
```

Hope it will help you :)