# (Xcode 8 Swift 3). Using Custom Keyboard Extension with a particular Text Field

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, keyboard

[image]

Since standard Number Pad keyboard has "empty" button, but doesn't have "+/-" button, I decided to create my own Keyboard Extension. I've done it.
[image]

But I don't know how to link (and invoke) it with a particular Text Field while other Text Fields using usual keyboards.
Is there any opportunity to apply  custom keyboardType like my own custom Keyboard?

Comment: Hi David Seek! Have a look on my last answer. I used solution with KeyboardDelegate protocol (I published my all relevant code below). I think Apple could implement such a keyboard as a default choice as well.

Comment: ah i see. allright! i was just going through my open answers and see if there is anything i can do. i was just curious because this question is still open as unanswered and unvoted. i'll just upvote your answer still you have been able to solve it yourself! have a good one buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution based on simular question: [How to input text using the buttons of an in-app custom keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33497693/how-to-input-text-using-the-buttons-of-an-in-app-custom-keyboard)

```
import UIKit

protocol KeyboardDelegate: class {
    func keyWasTapped(text: String)
}

class KeyboardView: UIView {

    // This variable will be set as the view controller so that
    // the keyboard can send messages to the view controller.
    weak var delegate: KeyboardDelegate?


    // MARK:- keyboard initialization
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initializeSubviews()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initializeSubviews()
    }

    func initializeSubviews() {
        let xibFileName = "KeyboardView" // xib extention not included
        let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(xibFileName, owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! UIView
        self.addSubview(view)
        view.frame = self.bounds
    }

    // MARK:- Button actions from .xib file    
    @IBAction func keyTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // When a button is tapped, send that information to the
        // delegate (ie, the view controller)
        self.delegate?.keyWasTapped(text: sender.titleLabel!.text!) // could alternatively send a tag value
    }

}
```

/* when error: "Could not load NIB in bundle"
 [Could not load NIB in bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337337/could-not-load-nib-in-bundle)
Visit the properties of the .xib files in the file inspector ，the property "Target Membership" pitch on the select box ，then your xib file was linked with your target
 */

In main ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, KeyboardDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var text1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var text2: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        // initialize custom keyboard
        let keyboardView = KeyboardView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 165))
        keyboardView.delegate = self // the view controller will be notified by the keyboard whenever a key is tapped

        // replace system keyboard with custom keyboard
        text1.inputView = keyboardView //accessoryView
        text1.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // required method for keyboard delegate protocol
    func keyWasTapped(text character: String) {

        if Int(character) != nil{
            text1.insertText(character)
        }

        if character == "⌫" {
            if !(text1.text?.isEmpty)! {
                let beforeText = text1.text!
                let truncated = beforeText.substring(to: beforeText.index(before: beforeText.endIndex))
                text1.text = truncated

            }
        }

        if character == "±" {
            let beforeText = text1.text!
            if var number = Int(beforeText) {
                number = -number
                text1.text = "\(number)"
            }
        }


    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        /*
        if (textField == self.text1) {
            //textField.inputView = keyboardView
        }
        */
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have coded a calculator for metric/imperial system. For that, I have coded my own keyboard, too.

[image]

I have set up the keyboard as `UIButtons` stacked within a Stack View.

[image]

The Buttons seem to be unknown for Xcode since I have just upgraded to Xcode 8 and the project is still in Swift 2.2.

[image]

Then I have set a UITextField and filled its `text` property using my buttons. This is for example the function for the Button `1` on my keyboard.

```
@IBOutlet weak var inputField: UITextField!
var numberStr:String = "0"
inputField.text = numberStr

@IBAction func oneKeyboardAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    if numberStr == "0" {
        numberStr = String(numberStr.characters.dropLast())
    }
    let newStr:String = numberStr + String("1")
    numberStr = newStr
    let dotToCommaString = newStr.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".", withString: ",")
    inputField.text = dotToCommaString
}
```

Also I have deactivated user interaction with the TextField, so the "original Keyboard" will not show.

**Edit**

Like mentioned in the comment section and to have my answer better fit your needs. You could set my custom keyboard into a `UIView` overlapping your `UIViewController` inside the Interface Builder. Set it as `MyKeyboardView.hidden = true` inside the `viewDidLoad()`.

Then you have your TextField where you want the custom Keyboard to be visible instead of the system one:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if (textField == self.yourDesiredTextField) { //the one where you want to use the custom keyboard 
        MyKeyboardView.hidden = false
    }
}
```

Then you add a gesture recognizer like that:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        MyKeyboardView.hidden = true


        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(gesture))
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func gesture() {

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2) {
            self.MyKeyboardView.hidden = true
        }

}
```

To have it little more smooth, I have added `animateWithDuration` when hiding the keyboard.

Comment: I understand your solution but one question: Can you hide your set of buttons (as a Keyboard) when tap anywhere:
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() 
    }

Comment: my keyboard can't be hidden like that since it's fixed part of the uiviewcontroller. but you could put it into a UIView and hide this view, even animated, by setting a gesture recognizer. no problem at all

Comment: my keyboard is set to be constant visible. like a hardware calculator, you know. but like said. put it into a UIView instead. hide it by default like `MyKeyboardView.hidden = true` and unhide it by func `textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {MyKeyboardView.hidden = false}` and hide it again using a gesture recognizer

Comment: I my case I need to hide and show different keyboards:
My own number keyboard (with "+/-") for a Text Field and a ASCII capable keyboard for a Text View.

Comment: no problem, i'll edit my answer to give you a better idea

Comment: By the way, I created my custom Keyboard based on this nice tutorial:
https://youtu.be/Bd-YqXsJrSk