# UIButtons pressed as Input for Text Field

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibutton, keyboard

Haven't found it on internet, searching on google I found Custom Keyboard as extension with is not what I need.

I need to make so that when you pressed my "Keyboard" on the bottom right (Its not actually a Keyboard, it is just a couple of UIButtons) the Inputs appear on the text field (Its the white space below ACTUAL CASH DEPOSIT).
[image]

So, when you press the text field, no keyboard should Appear, and When I start pressing the buttons of my "Custom Keyboard" the numbers should Appear.

I have found something similar in [(Xcode 8 Swift 3). Using Custom Keyboard Extension with a particular Text Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677776/xcode-8-swift-3-using-custom-keyboard-extension-with-a-particular-text-field) But On my other Tap, Denominations I have multiple Input Fields. Like his image:
[image]

I know how to do all the code behind in terms of buttons pressed and calculations But I don't know how to make the input fields as a responder for my custom Keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make it magically update - instead, I'd suggest binding all the buttons to a single function, and then then for instance use the `tag` property in IB to differentiate between them. Through that function update the text.

```
func didPressButton(button: UIButton) {
  switch button.tag{
  case 1: myTextField.text! += "1"
  default: break
  }
}
```

I'd caution you'll need to do some verification logic if you allow decimals so all numbers are valid.